# UPDATE a column in one table according to a column in another

Tags: postgresql, update

In Postgres, I have two tables that have become de-normalized. We're in the process of migrating to a normalized form, but in the meantime the tables have become out of sync. I'd like to copy the values for the `native_name` column from the `native_name_aliases` table into the `dpoint` table. Here is my attempt:

```
update dpoint
set native_name = (select
                      nna.native_name
                    from
                        native_name_aliases as nna
                    LEFT JOIN
                      dpoint as d
                    ON
                      d.dpoint_id = nna.dpoint_id)
where building_id = 42;
```

I get an error message:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

My `native_name_aliases` table has fields `id, native_name, dpoint_id, building_id`.
And the `dpoint` table has `dpoint_id, building_id, native_name` and a bunch of other irrelevant fields.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is ***uncorrelated*** and returns all rows from the join between `native_name_aliases` and `dpoint`, where only a single row would be allowed. I guess this is what you are after:

```
UPDATE dpoint d
SET    native_name = nna.native_name
FROM   native_name_aliases nna
WHERE  d.building_id = 42
AND    d.dpoint_id = nna.dpoint_id
AND    d.native_name IS DISTINCT FROM nna.native_name;
```

You did not provide table definitions and Postgres version, so I can't tell for sure.

The last line is to prevent expensive "empty" updates. Details:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)